# X86 browser (cefsharp) can't run on some X64 computer

Tags: c#, windows, browser, cefsharp

I write a browser by using cefsharp by C#, I debug and released it on both X86 and X64 platform by using vs2015, and I made a Installation package by using Inno Software. I tried to run it on different computers, both the X86 and X64 browser could run on my computer, my computer is X64 win10.

But when I ran the X86 version on my friend A's computer(win7,X64), the browser couldn't work. So I run the X86 version on my friend B's computer(win10,X64), it could work. I am confused why the X86 version couldn't run on A's computer.

Here is the error info I recieved:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more info than "couldnt work" ..

Comment: Is the version of .Net you are targetting installed on the PC where your application doesn't work?

Comment: The error info in on below, the .net framework is 4.6

Comment: X64 version could run on A's computer

Comment: Almost certainly due to not having the *correct* version of `Visual Studio C++ Redistributable 2013` installed on those systems. Even if your system is 64bit and your browser is built for `x86`, your users MUST install `vc_redist.x86.exe` as the browser is `x86`. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Answer (score 0):

Another case I've experienced is setting `max_old_space_size` to a large value which causes render subprocess to crash on startup when running in `32bit` mode.

Answer (score -1):

Just a probably reason is that Windows 10's compiler is different from window 7, since they all 64 bits system, so both of they make a virtualization of the same 32 bits system.
So, if you want to run the 64 bits chrome on windows 7, you must compile again with the compiler of windows 7.